# Movendo(drag) três divs ao mesmo tempo e desativando com um checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Estou utilizando este código para mover divs de forma simultanea:
https://github.com/someshwara/MultiDraggable

A lógica: Se checkbox marcado, utilizar 'drag em grupo', senão, utilizar 'drag por unidade'.

Porém uma vez desmarcado o checkbox (para utilizar 'drag por unidade') o mesmo
não está funcionando como deveria como no exemplo a seguir:
https://jsfiddle.net/L56yvyms/1/

```
            $('document').ready(function() {


              $("#checkboxDragAll").click(function() {

                if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
                {

                    //Se 'checkbox marcado' drag funciona em "grupo"
                        $(".d").multiDraggable({
                          group: $(".d")
                        });

                    //Setando o drag em .d2 em "unidade"
                        // $(".d").multiDraggable({
                        //  group: ""
                        //});


                } else {
                          //Se 'checkbox desmarcado' drag deveria funcionar em "unidade"!!!
                          // Mas se anteriormente setado em "grupo", 
                          // o drag em "unidade" não está funcionando.

                          $(".d").draggable( "destroy" );
                          $(".d").draggable();


                };

              });
            });
```

Somebody save me? :B

Comment: E.. lhe entendo :) Mas dei uma olhada, há problemas mesmo no "destroy" do draggable. Pelo que vi ao desmarcar, ele faz um de cada vez, ou seja, ao marcar e desmarcar 3 vezes ele funcionar :P...

Comment: Hum, deixa eu dar uma olhadinha nisso, se for assim é só fazer um each nas divs eu acho =)

Comment: Isso que pensei.. mas não deu certo, fiz alguns testes com o `each`

Comment: É eu testei e não deu certo tmb Samir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após uma boa pesquisada achei uma espécie de aprimoramento dessa função `multiDraaggable()`. Você pode vê-lo aqui: https://github.com/wizztjh/MultiDraggable/blob/master/multidraggable.js

Ele basicamente  acrescenta isso ao código:

```
if (opts == "destroy") {
  return this.each(function() {
    $(this)
      .draggable("destroy")
      .unbind(".multiDraggable")
      .data("init", "");
  });
}
```

Além de fazer algumas pequenas modificações, porém bem interessantes, ao meu ver. Por isso, lhe aconselho a seguir esse update.

Com essas alterações, agora possuímos o argumento `"destroy"`, igualmente ao `.draggable('destroy')` "nativo". Sendo assim, basta fazer isso no seu código:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $("#checkboxDragAll").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(".d").multiDraggable({
        group: $('.d')
      });
    } else {
      $(".d").multiDraggable('destroy');
      $(".d").draggable()
    };
  });
});
```

Você pode ver em funcionamento aqui abaixo:

### [Demonstração - JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/L56yvyms/2/)

Comment: Poxa Samir, você é demais, muito obrigado mesmo de coração! =) Já estou abrindo a página =D

Comment: @user31050 Valeu cara rsrs, feliz em ter ajudado.. :)